# Specify a Directory for Save in Mathematica

Tags: directory, wolfram-mathematica, save

Considering :

```
ALLdwafDif[#] & /@ symmetries

Save["ALLL.m", ALLL]
```

Is there a way to save the results in a particular directory ? It automatically save the results in my user directory now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current working directory is given by `Directory[]`. You can set it by `SetDirectory[]`. Alternatively, you can append the directory name to `ALLL.m` and it works.

eg

```
f = 5;
Save["~/Desktop/temp.m", f]
```

does what you'd expect (`~` is a shortcut for home directory on most Unices, and mma respects it, so this gets saved on my desktop)

Comment: Thank You. So : Save["ALLL.m/Users/LAEH/Dropbox/", ALLL] would do it  ?

Comment: Got It, I had them around to me I need to "prepend" the directory !

Comment: @500 Yes, and you could also use `"~/Dropbox/ALLL.m"` for clarity (to the extend that a variable named ALLL can be clear!). You could also switch the current working directory to wherever it is you want, eg `SetDirectory["~/Dropbox"]`,  whence you could simply use `Save["ALLL.m", ALLL]` and it'll save it in the right place.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the default working directory permanently you can add something like `SetDirectory["new_dir"];` to one of the files `$BaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m` or `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m` (which one depends on whether you want to change the default directory for all users or for the current user only). Next time you restart Mathematica, `Directory[]` will then automatically be set to `new_dir`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Save[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "All.m"], ALLL]
```

brings up a standard system save-file dialog box and saves your file after you've chosen a location (and a new file name if you have chosen one).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I find it useful to save data in the same location as the notebook:

```
f = 5;
Save[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "f.dat"}], f]
```

Or to save in your (default) Dropbox directory:

```
Save[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Dropbox", "f.dat"}], f]
```

I rarely use the directory stack that's controlled by `SetDirectory[]` and friends.

Comment: If you save often in that directory it would be shorter to just declare that directory the current directory with `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]`. Putting this line in an initialisation cell of your notebook means you don't have to change all the `Save["ALLL.m", ALLL]` lines you already have in the notebook.